# \ref{figures} goes to the part, not the figure

Tags: floats, cross-referencing, minipage

I'm using Latex for a Report about signal processing and I've a lot of figures. SoI putted them into minipages to display them side by side.
It's fine but the references doesn't work.
Here is an example:

```
\part{Figures}
\section{Question 2}
\begin{figure}[ht]
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.45\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{21comp.eps}
    \label{fig:21comp}
    \caption{Comparaison des réponses impulsionnelles des filtres $h_1[m]$ et $h_2[m]$}
\end{minipage}
\hspace{0.5cm}
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.45\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{21comp2.eps}
    \label{fig:21comp2}
    \caption{Comparaison des filtres $h_1[m]$ et d'un filtre passe-bas parfait}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
```

For me it seems to be fine but when I try to use a reference like \ref{fig:21comp}, it displays only A (the part) and not 1 for the figure number.

What am I doing wrong ?
Is it related with my minipages ?

Thanks.

Comment: I tried inverting caption and label and it does nothing...

Comment: @Gp2mv3 after inverting them, compile twice.

Comment: Ok, five compilations worked... Maybe Tex-Maker related... Thanks for your help !

Comment: Incidentally, the `\centering` instructions inside the `minipage` environments are redundant, as you're setting the widths of the graphs to take up the full space that's available.